# Autocomplete onItemClickListener event not triggering?

Tags: android

I am using autocomplete to fetch places from the google API. Its working fine.Its fetching all the places to drop down but the thing is if I click on the item, onItemClick listener is not working for autocomplete.

This is the code

```
   ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
            {
                values.add(result.get(i).get("description"));
            }


            PlacesAdapter placesAdapter=new PlacesAdapter(getActivity(),values);
            // Setting the adapter
            tempAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownVerticalOffset(20);
            tempAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(placesAdapter);
            tempAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "place"+postion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tempAutoCompleteTextView.setText(result.get(position).get("description"));
                }
            });
```

This code is constructor of PlacesAdapter

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> list;
private Activity mContext;
public PlacesAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<String> list) {
    super(context,list.size(),list);
    this.list = list;
    mContext = context;
}
```

Comment: you are using custom view?

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `itemSelectedListener` instead for that purpose.

```
  tempAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


            }
        });
```

Comment: please debug and check whether it is called or not . if not then also check same procedure with onItemClick Listener. @ramyabr

Comment: please extend your arrayadaptor with string class `extends ArrayAdapter<String>` . and check `OnItemClick listner` again.

Comment: ya that is one of the reasons and I have done the mistake in the adapter class which i returns item null.now its working fine .Thank you

Comment: @KDeogharkar ty so much